# What's the purpose of $scope in scala.Predef?

Tags: xml, scala, scope, library-design

`scala.Predef` contains the following code:

```
// Apparently needed for the xml library
val $scope = scala.xml.TopScope
```

Did someone figure out why it is necessary, considering that it creates dependencies to packages which could have been easily split out of the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/SymbolicXMLBuilder.scala`, and the result of parsing an XML literal.

```
scala -Xprint:parser -e '<node/>'

new _root_.scala.xml.Elem(null, "node", _root_.scala.xml.Null, $scope)
```

Ideally this would be moved somewhere under `scala.xml`; try it and see what breaks.